# Insert an XML file to \data\data directory in an nonroot android system

Tags: android, xml

Assume that I have file XML like this :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="ActivationCode">c4ec5e61f49897192ad0744b27ad985f31d84a3458aeec628b5df809a246c1418ce4b52e9d07d15ab2377fd1e946fe1ad880ee8ca6359d0bda7e6502c10494d4ec612624f28b43727f2b6e5ec18959c53ebc90f97c636c5fe787f513c0a851686b2ccf1e8592df21e2a8d9370103750220ec47ff8267d036841592dc3e110334de8f136e2af9c1f100ba9a64fc7974ea</string>
</map>
```

I want to insert this file into this directory in non-rooted Android system :

\data\data\com.mycompany.my\shared_prefs\

How can I resolve this problem... All answer would be appreciated..thanks

Comment: Why should you do that?

Comment: you can save that file without rooting your phone if your app owns that folder.

Comment: use shared preference. Android will handle this. You don't need to write a file.

Comment: Could you please explain me more about this

Answer (score 1):

**Store to sharedpreferences:**

```
 //Creating or modifying preference
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Activation", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

 //editor.putString("KEY","Value");
 editor.putString("ActivationCode", "c4ec5e61f49897192ad0744b27ad985f31d84a3458aeec628b5df809a246c1418ce4b52e9d07d15ab2377fd1e946fe1ad880ee8ca6359d0bda7e6502c10494d4ec612624f28b43727f2b6e5ec18959c53ebc90f97c636c5fe787f513c0a851686b2ccf1e8592df21e2a8d9370103750220ec47ff8267d036841592dc3e110334de8f136e2af9c1f100ba9a64fc7974ea");
 editor.commit();
```

**Retrieve from sharedpreferences:**

```
 SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences("Activation", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 //sh.getString("KEY","Default value");
 String activation = sh.getString("ActivationCode",null);
```

**for more please ref:** http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: I don't know anything about programming

Comment: @Mehran Then you shouldn't program. OR you should study before trying to.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thank you. I add the retrieve code and ref link.